# Call objective blocks in a swift class

Tags: ios, swift, block

I'm trying to use an objective C library, in a objective C i'm using it like this  :

```
 [animationView setDraggingMovedBlock:^(UIView * view){
   //some code
}];
```

I don't know how to call it in a swift class.

Comment: try if it solves your problem I am not sure but may be it'll help you **animationView.draggingMovedBlock = {(_ view: UIView?) -> Void in
    //some code
}**

Comment: works like a charm thks

Comment: okay posting as a answer please vote and accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
  animationView.draggingMovedBlock = {(_ view: UIView?) -> Void in
     //some code
  }
```